# Not able to Concatenate the HTML Code in PHP

Tags: php, html

This is my function `display_image` in which i am checking if the variable `$card1` is `0`, then i can set image as `1_AC.png` else `redback.png` for **Card 1** and then i am checking if `$card2` is `0` then set image as `2_AD.png` for **Card 2** else `redback.png` and so on..

What i want to do is i want to concatenate the `<img src>` of `$card1` with `<img src>` of `$card2` with `<img scr>` of `$card3` and so on based on the values of `$card1, $card2`, etc

i am little confused, how can i achieve this ??

```
if($card1=='0'){  
$data = '
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <img src = "https://www.stoningtonsoccerinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/1_AC.png" height="5" width="5" >
        </body>
    </html>';   
}else{
    $data = '
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <img src = "https://www.stoningtonsoccerinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/red_back.png" height="5" width="5" >
        </body>
    </html>';
}

//card2 setting and fixing of front and back

if($card2=='0'){
    $data = '
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <img src = "https://www.stoningtonsoccerinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/2_AD.png" height="5" width="5" >
        </body>
    </html>';

}else{

    $data = '
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <img src = "https://www.stoningtonsoccerinternational.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/red_back.png" height="5" width="5" >
        </body>
    </html>';
}
    return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation is simple in PHP.

- First, move the `<html>` and `<head>` and `<body>` tags out side your the individual card.
- Then change the assignment of all `$data` the cards to `.=` instead of `=`

Like this:

```
 $data = "<html><head></head> <body>";

 if($card1=='0'){
    $data .= '<img src = "url 1" height="5" width="5" >';
 }else{
    $data . = '<img src = "url 2" height="5" width="5" >
  }

 // ...and so on...
```

If they're all just 2 options for each card, you could even use a ternary:

```
$data .= $card1=='0' ? '<img src = "url 1" height="5" width="5" >' : 
                       '<img src = "url 2" height="5" width="5" >' ;
```

Then once your done with the conditionals for each card, append the closing `<body>` and `<html>` tags:

```
$data .= "</body></html>"
```

Here's a reference to the docs to concatentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php